# Sending data to two channels, the second channel might receive data first sometime

Tags: go

```
package main

func m() {
    c1 := make(chan int, 1)
    c2 := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        c1 <- 1
        c2 <- 1
    }()
    select {
    case <-c1:
    case <-c2:
        println("no way")
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        m()
    }
}
```

There are two channels `c1`, `c2`.

We are sending data to `c1` and `c2` in a goroutine. And we have a `select` to receive the data from these two channels and return.

The question is: we are send data to `c1` first and receive from `c1` first in most cases. But sometimes we receive from `c2` first when sending to `c1` first. Why？

Answer (score 1):

[The order of message receiving in the select statement is pseudo-random.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

Comment: Maybe that two sending operations are running in a different thread when we put them in a goroutine?  So we can't guarantee to read them in order?